# why does gmapping only return a map with 0 and 100 but no other values?

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone

I'm using slam gmapping to produce a map, but I've noticed that the output Occupancy Grid Map(which is broadcast to topic /map) contains only -1,0 and 100 for unknown, free and occupied grids respectively.

I'm wondering is there a way to produce a map with other values say 0.05, 0.37, 0.52 etc. which represent the probability of the grid to be occupied? I've checked out the parameters available for gmapping but could not find a clue about this.If it's not available in gmapping, then how should I do this?

any help will be much appreciated, thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229433/why-does-gmapping-only-return-a-map-with-0-and-100-but-no-other-values?/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the `GMapping::ScanMatcherMap` object contains the probabilities of occupancy all the cells as floating numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 : https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L690
If you can publish it to a topic you might get what you want.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0